# how to pass array into database

Tags: php, sql, arrays, insert

I am trying to pass arrays into a database but can't get it right.
I have following db rows

```
Country, number, Page, date
```

And want something like this in my database

```
id    Country  number   Page   date
2     Sweden   5        cat    14th june 2015
      United   10       ind    14th june 2015   
      states   58       con    14th june 2015    
      France   101      aces   14th june 2015      
      Germany  200      ind    14th june 2015
```

I am using this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$new_res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `em-res_db` VALUES('','$Country','$number','$Page','$date')");  
                if ($new_res){
                    //continue
    }
```

I hope you get the picture of what I'm trying to do

Comment: I guess you'll have to loop the `POST`

Comment: 1) ***Stop*** using the ***deprecated*** `mysql` extension, switch to `PDO` or `mysqli` instead. 2) Learn about [injection](http://bobby-tables.com), and prepared statements. 3) Use prepared statements, and execute them using an array of values. 3b) If `id` is your PK, and an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field, then don't insert an empty string as value, just specify the fields you're actually setting, and let the DB handle the auto increment stuff.

Comment: Where are your database connection? What error it produce?

Comment: my connection mysql_connect ('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db ('my db');

Comment: all I see in my db is array()

Comment: where is your array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a loop who have the same length as the array, and in the loop insert the code where you are inserting data to the db.

Example

```
for(i=0;i<=count(array)-1;i++){
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$new_res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `em-res_db` VALUES('','$Country','$number','$Page','$date')");  
                if ($new_res){
                    //continue
    }
}
```